# giving a name to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

When I look to a pd df :

[image]

I tell myself I would like to fill the upper left empty space by a dataframe name. Is that possible ?

(Here it would be to put a text on the empty cell on top of "Lib_ze" and on left of "nunique".)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible if set columns names:

```
df.columns.name = 'text'
```

Or [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename) (new in `pandas` `0.18.0`):

```
df = df.rename_axis('text', axis=1)
```

Sample:

```
df = df.rename_axis('text', axis=1)
print (df)
text              nunique
Lib_ze                295
cd_cmn              31870
cd_ze                 295
code_commune_zdc    31870
unite                 638
```

If set index name:

```
#df.index.name = 'text'
df = df.rename_axis('text')
print (df)
                  nunique
text                     
Lib_ze                295
cd_cmn              31870
cd_ze                 295
code_commune_zdc    31870
unite                 638
```

Comment: Any way to do this during dataframe creation, i.e. can I pass that name as an argument to `pd.DataFrame(...)`?

Comment: Doesn't that actually give a name to the **index** rather than the DataFrame itself?

Comment: @Casimir You can add your own index (e.g. a `range`) and use it as index as such: `df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'col2': pd.Series([2, 4, 6, 8]), 'my_index': range(4)}).set_index('my_index')`

Comment: @Casimir  If we accept that it's just naming the index, one can name the index explicitly. `pd.DataFrame(index=pd.Index([1, 2, 3], name="foo"))`